# locastorage save selection javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

```html
<select id="Gender" onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
        <option value="">Choose Gender</option>
        <option value="men">Men</option>
        <option value="wemen">Wemen</option>
        <option value="girls">Girls</option>
        <option value="boys">boys</option>
    </select>  
    <br>
       <br>
    <select id="men" name="subselector" style="display:none">
      <option value="">Choose an item</option> 
      <option value="tsm">T-Shirt</option>
      <option value="lsm">long sleeve</option>
     <option value="tankm">Tank Top</option>
     <option value="fzhm">Full zip Hood</option>
     <option value="pohm">Pull over Hood</option>
     <option value="fzfm">Full zip Fleece</option>
     <option value="fm">Fleece</option>
    </select>  
 
    
    <select id="wemen" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="slw">short sleeve</option>
 
    </select>  
    
     <select id="girls" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="shortsg">shorts</option>
        
    </select>  
 <select id="boys" name="subselector" style="display:none">
        <option value="tshirtb">tshirt</option>
       
    </select>  
     <div style='display:none;' id="wsl">
                       <div class="colore white" data-image="https://opensource.org/files/osi_keyhole_300X300_90ppi.png">
                </div>
                <div class="colore black" data-image="http://mebe.co/ford">
                </div>
                <div class="colore yellow" data-image="http://mebe.co/f150">
                </div>
                <div class="colore orange" data-image="http://mebe.co/yukon">
                </div>
                <div class="colore red" data-image="http://mebe.co/370z">
                </div>
            </div>
            
              <div style='display:none;' id="mtsm">
    <div class="colore white active" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/white.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/whiteback.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore black" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/black.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/whiteback.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore yellow" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/yellow.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/orange.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore orange" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/orange.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/yellow.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore red" data-image="http://torcdesign.com/shirts/red.jpg" data-image-back="http://amp.site88.net/shirts/black.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

i would like to know how i can display an image on a second page using the information the user selected on drop down i was told to use localstorage but i have not been able to make it work can someone please teach me exactly how to save selection of all the drop downs the user picks? all i need is to save the selection from the previous page and i will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can save all the values in object and then set it to local storage using .

```
var vals = {
  gender:"male" // object structure example
}; 
localstorage.setItem('nameforvalues', JSON.stringify(vals));
```

Than after moving to second page

You can get the object using

```
var storedvals = local storage.getItem('nameforvalues');
storedvals = JSON.parse(storedvals);
```

Comment: can you please type in jsfiddle so i can see where the code starts and ends please

Answer (score 0):

That should give you a direction:

```js
        function save() {
          localStorage.setItem("selection", document.getElementById("Gender").value);
        }

        window.onload = function() {
          console.log(localStorage.getItem("selection"));
        }
```

```html
<select id="Gender" onchange="save()">
  <option value="">Choose Gender</option>
  <option value="men">Men</option>
  <option value="wemen">Wemen</option>
  <option value="girls">Girls</option>
  <option value="boys">boys</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i dont need to put them together in both of my pages do i?

Comment: You use save() on the first page, load() on the second, if I understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: im really sorry for taking your time. this is not working thank you for your time

Comment: And what does your code look like now? Does it manager to find local storage? Does it saved the values?

Comment: I put the same code you posted but I guess that I needed to make more code

Comment: You can't simply copy-paste code and expect it to work. Please check my example again, understand how it works, and try to apply it to your code. Hope it helps.